# JS safety when accessing variables outside of the async function

Tags: javascript, multithreading, async-await, thread-safety

I have an async function here, since the `messageQueue` is changed outside, I want to know if it's safe to be written like this.

```
this.messageQueue.push(message1);
onChatMessage();
... // some other code
this.messageQueue.push(message2);
onChatMessage();
... // some other code
this.messageQueue.push(message3);
onChatMessage();
...

onChatMessage: async function () {
    if (this.isProcessMsgQ) { return; }
    this.isProcessMsgQ = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.messageQueue.length; i++) {
        const msg = this.messageQueue[i];
        try {
            await this.processMessage(msg);
        } catch (err) {
        }
    }
    this.messageQueue = [];
    this.isProcessMsgQ = false;
},
```

my worry is that, for `thread1`, right after `this.messageQueue = [];` and before `this.isProcessMsgQ = false;`, could `thread2` finish the process from adding `message2` to the queue, going into `onChatMessage`, checking `this.isProcessMsgQ`, and return?
if yes, then there's the case that messsage2 will not be processed, any idea to deal with it?

Thanks!

Comment: nothing else can run `right after this.messageQueue = []; and before this.isProcessMsgQ = false;` synchronous code runs synchronously

Comment: also, what is "thread1" and "thread2" ... are you using *workers* ?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. It can only schedule functions to be called in the future. In your concrete example, ignoring `// some other code`, `this.message = [];` of the first `onChatMessage()` call  wouldn't even be executed until the last `onChatMessage()` call happened. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: By thread1 and thread2, do you mean the respective calls of `onChatMessage` for message1 and message2?

Comment: @Bravo, just like @richytong said, `thread1` is the first call of `onChatMessage`, and `thread2` is the second call, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to lose messages between the start of your for loop and when you set `this.messageQueue = []`. Any messages that are added in that time frame will be lost when you reassign `this.messageQueue`. To prevent this, use a Promise to track the completion of the message executions, refreshing the queue at the very begining before any of the executions have begun.

```js
onChatMessage: function () {
    if (this.isProcessMsgQ) { return; }
    this.isProcessMsgQ = true;
    const tmp = this.messageQueue
    this.messageQueue = []
    this.executingAll = Promise.all(
      tmp.map(msg => this.processMessage(msg).catch(() => {}))
    ).then(() => {
      this.isProcessMsgQ = false
    })
},
```